# Portable way to customize executable called by script

Tags: shell-script

I have a script that I need to instrument. Suppose it calls a `foo` program.

I can define `foo` function and export it to sub-shell, thus providing instrumented `foo` call. This works only if script executes under 'compatible' shell.

Is there a more portable solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use a shell wrapper?

```
mv foo foo.real
cat >foo <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
... whatever instrumentation ...
exec foo.real "$@"
EOF
chmod +x foo
```

This will fail if `foo` needs to be called `foo`, in which case `PATH` tricks may be necessary, or to move `foo` to a say `libexec` directory or such. Skip the `exec` bit if post-run instrumentation must also happen.